# Annotations are not showing in MKMapView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, mkmapview, foursquare

I am doing a projects by following this tutorial [enter link description here](https://www.appcoda.com/foursquare-realm-swift/) in swift3 Xcode 8.2.1.

I want to get 10 Nearest Restaurants from my current location.

But Still I can't get any data as map pins or tableview.

Please help me I am new to Swift.

Please find whole coding here including pod file.

**Pod File**

```
'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target "FSResturant" do
    
pod 'QuadratTouch',
:git => 'https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/das-quadrat', :branch => 'fry-swift30'

pod 'RealmSwift'

end
```

**ResturantAPI.swift**

```
import Foundation
import QuadratTouch
import MapKit
import Realm
import RealmSwift



//Create Venues Struct
struct API
{
  struct notifications
  {
    static let venuesUpdated = "venues_updated"
  }

}



class ResturantAPI
{
    static let sharedInstance = ResturantAPI()
    var session:Session?
    
    init()
    {
        // Initialize the Foursquare client API Keys
        let client = Client(clientID: "XXXX", clientSecret: "XXXX", redirectURL: "")
        
        let configuration = Configuration(client:client)
        Session.setupSharedSessionWithConfiguration(configuration)
        
        self.session = Session.sharedSession()
    }
    
   //getting venue data from FOURSQUARE 
    func getResturantsWithLocation(location:CLLocation)
    {
        //function body
        if let session = self.session
        {
            //this category Id will receive nearby halal resturants in dubai
            var parameters = location.parameters()
            parameters += [Parameter.categoryId: "52e81612bcbc57f1066b79ff"]
            parameters += [Parameter.radius: "2000"]
            parameters += [Parameter.limit: "10"]
            
            // Start a "search", i.e. an async call to Foursquare that should return venue data
            let searchTask = session.venues.search(parameters)
            {
                (result) -> Void in
                
                if let response = result.response
                {
                    if let venues = response["venues"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]
                    {
                        autoreleasepool
                            {
                                let realm = try! Realm()
                                realm.beginWrite()
                                
                                for venue:[String: AnyObject] in venues
                                {
                                    let venueObject:Venue = Venue()
                                    
                                    if let id = venue["id"] as? String
                                    {
                                        venueObject.id = id
                                    }
                                    
                                    if let name = venue["name"] as? String
                                    {
                                        venueObject.name = name
                                    }
                                    
                                    if  let location = venue["location"] as? [String: AnyObject]
                                    {
                                        if let longitude = location["lng"] as? Float
                                        {
                                            venueObject.longitude = longitude
                                        }
                                        
                                        if let latitude = location["lat"] as? Float
                                        {
                                            venueObject.latitude = latitude
                                        }
                                        
                                        if let formattedAddress = location["formattedAddress"] as? [String]
                                        {
                                            venueObject.address = formattedAddress.joined(separator: " ")
                                        }
                                    }
                                    
                                    realm.add(venueObject, update: true)
                                }
                                
                                do {
                                    try realm.commitWrite()
                                    print("Committing write...")
                                }
                                catch (let e)
                                {
                                    print("Y U NO REALM ? \(e)")
                                }
                        }
                        
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Foundation.Notification.Name(rawValue: API.notifications.venuesUpdated), object:nil, userInfo:nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            searchTask.start()
        }
        
    }
}
extension CLLocation
    {
        func parameters() -> Parameters
        {
            let ll      = "\(self.coordinate.latitude),\(self.coordinate.longitude)"
            
         //  let near = "Dubai"
            
            let llAcc   = "\(self.horizontalAccuracy)"
         //   let llAcc = "10000.0"
            
           let alt     = "\(self.altitude)"
          //  let alt = "0"
            
           let altAcc  = "\(self.verticalAccuracy)"
         //   let altAcc = "10000.0"
         
         //   let query = "resturants"
            
            let parameters = [
                Parameter.ll:ll,
              // Parameter.near:near,
                Parameter.llAcc:llAcc,
                Parameter.alt:alt,
                Parameter.altAcc:altAcc,
              //  Parameter.query:query
            ]
            return parameters
            
          
        }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import RealmSwift
import Realm


class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    //Initialize the Map View
    @IBOutlet var mapView:MKMapView?
    
    //To get the user location
    var locationManager:CLLocationManager?
   
    //Span view in meters default
    let distanceSpan:Double = 500
    
    //show user's location on the map
    var lastLocation:CLLocation?
    
    // Stores venues from Realm, as a non-lazy list
    var venues:[Venue]?
    
    //Initializing the table view
    @IBOutlet var tableView1:UITableView?
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.onVenuesUpdated(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: API.notifications.venuesUpdated), object: nil);
        
        


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        //Initializing mapview delegate to display
        
        if let mapView = self.mapView
        {
           mapView.delegate = self
        }
        
        //Initializing UITableview delegate to display
        
        if let tableView1 = self.tableView1
        {
          tableView1.delegate = self
          tableView1.dataSource = self
            
        
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        if locationManager == nil
        {
          locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            
          locationManager!.delegate = self
          locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
          locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            
          // Don't send location updates with a distance smaller than 50 meters between them
          locationManager!.distanceFilter = 50
          locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    
// UITable View Delegates
    
    func tableView(_ tableView1: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return venues?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView1: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView1: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier");
        
        if cell == nil
        {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
        }
        
        if let venue = venues?[indexPath.row]
        {
            cell!.textLabel?.text = venue.name
            cell!.detailTextLabel?.text = venue.address
        }
        
        return cell!
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView1: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let venue = venues?[indexPath.row]
        {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(venue.latitude), longitude: Double(venue.longitude)), distanceSpan, distanceSpan)
            mapView?.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            
        
        }
    }
    
    
    func refreshVenues(_ location: CLLocation?, getDataFromFoursquare:Bool = false)
    {
        if location != nil
        {
            lastLocation = location
        }
        
        if let location = lastLocation
        {
            if getDataFromFoursquare == true
            {
                ResturantAPI.sharedInstance.getResturantsWithLocation(location: location)
            }
            
            // Convenience method to calculate the top-left and bottom-right GPS coordinates based on region (defined with distanceSpan)
            let (start, stop) = calculateCoordinatesWithRegion(location);
            
            // Set up a predicate that ensures the fetched venues are within the region
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "latitude < %f AND latitude > %f AND longitude > %f AND longitude < %f", start.latitude, stop.latitude, start.longitude, stop.longitude);

            let realm = try! Realm()
            
            venues = realm.objects(Venue.self).filter(predicate).sorted {
                location.distance(from: $0.coordinate) < location.distance(from: $1.coordinate);
            };
            
            for venue in venues!
            {
                let annotation = ResturantAnnotation(title: venue.name, subtitle: venue.address, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(venue.latitude), longitude: Double(venue.longitude)));
                
                mapView?.addAnnotation(annotation);
            }
             // RELOAD ALL THE DATAS !!!
            tableView1?.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    
    //Delegate Method of CLLocation Manager
    
    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation)
    {
        if let mapView = self.mapView
        {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, distanceSpan, distanceSpan)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            
            refreshVenues(newLocation, getDataFromFoursquare: true)
        }
    }
    
    //Adds Annotations in the Map View
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
    {
        if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self)
        {
            return nil
        }
        
        var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "annotationIdentifier");
        
        if view == nil
        {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "annotationIdentifier")
        }
        
        view?.canShowCallout = true
        
        return view
    }
    
    func onVenuesUpdated(_ notification:Foundation.Notification)
    {
        // When new data from Foursquare comes in, reload from local Realm
        refreshVenues(nil);
    }
    
    func calculateCoordinatesWithRegion(_ location:CLLocation) -> (CLLocationCoordinate2D, CLLocationCoordinate2D)
    {
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, distanceSpan, distanceSpan);
        
        var start:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D();
        var stop:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D();
        
        start.latitude  = region.center.latitude  + (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
        start.longitude = region.center.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
        stop.latitude   = region.center.latitude  - (region.span.latitudeDelta  / 2.0);
        stop.longitude  = region.center.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
        
        return (start, stop);
    }
```

**Venue.swift**

import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import MapKit

```
class Venue: Object
{
    dynamic var id:String = ""
    dynamic var name:String = ""
    
    dynamic var latitude:Float = 0
    dynamic var longitude:Float = 0
    
    dynamic var address:String = ""
    
    var coordinate:CLLocation {
        return CLLocation(latitude: Double(latitude), longitude: Double(longitude));
    }
    //The the primary key to Realm
    override static func primaryKey() -> String?
    {
        return "id";
    }
    
}
```

**ResturantAnnotation.swift**

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class ResturantAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation
{
    let title:String?
    let subtitle:String?
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    
    init(title:String?, subtitle:String?, coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D)
    {
        self.title=title
        self.subtitle=subtitle
        self.coordinate=coordinate
        
        super.init();
    }
}
```

Can Anybody figure out what is the mistake here, that not showing responses in the map and tableview.

Thanks.

Comment: Simply debug the code and check this line is executed or not `mapView?.addAnnotation(annotation)`?

Comment: Please check if you are getting any response from the api call or not.

Comment: @sourav No I'm not getting any responses from the server. Meanwhile I am getting this error.                                                                                    ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1230.32.8.29.9/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1763: InfoLog SolidRibbonShader:
ERROR /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1230.32.8.29.9/GeoGL/GeoGL/GLCoreContext.cpp 1764: WARNING: Output of vertex shader 'v_gradient' not read by fragment shader

Comment: Then how you are suppose to show the annotation ? And i guess that will be a totally new question you are asking about.

Comment: I doubt that the predicate is wrong. Please check No predicate code: `realm.objects(Venue.self).filter(predicate).sorted` -> `realm.objects(Venue.self).sorted`